# Power Apps - Office 365 Outlook permissons

Tags: outlook, office365, powerapps, power-automate

I have a Power App that, with a button, starts a Flow. The Flow is only using a Gmail-send email-component to send an email. From the Power App to the Flow i pass some values that will be included in the email.

Why do I get the promt of Office 365 Outlook permissions? Are those permissions really needed?

I'm not using the Office 365 Outlook-connection. Also I tried to remove all Office 365 Outlook-connectors without success, both in the Power App and in the Flow.

Answer (score 0):

This is default behaviour of Powerapp. When you share the app, you will be asked to share your connection. In some resources are shared automatically, while other resources require shared users for the app to work

Kindly do check the below link for more info:
https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/share-app-resources/

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using a second flow that is started by the first flow that Power Apps starts. The second flow is started via HTTP-component.